# Insert into table search_index in Prestashop fails

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I have absolutely no idea whats going on.

I'm trying `INSERT` into table `ps_search_index` like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ps_search_index (id_product,id_word,weight)
         VALUES ('.$id_product.','.$getID.',9)';
Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql);
```

and it doesn't work if there is `$id_product`.

But its working when i write eg. 1234. `id_product` is of course `INT` and any other value in this place working.

Of course no other errors.
Whats should i do?

Comment: I can only imagine that `$id_product` is not set properly? if you `var_dump($id_product);` is anything being shown?

Comment: Yes it's eg.  1340, which works perfect for other column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this using tutorial:
http://blog.belvg.com/developer-tips-how-prestashop-search-works.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('
    INSERT INTO '._DB_PREFIX_.'search_index (id_product, id_word, weight)
    VALUES ('.(int)$id_product.', '.(int)$getID.', 9)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight)', false
);
```

I always recommend to cast the var. In this case you have to add `ON DUPLICATE...`, like is do in the `Search` class.

Comment: Not working. only ps_search_word is updating great, but _index no

Answer (score 1):

In `ps_search_index` database table of PrestaShop, the combination of `id_product` and `id_word` is the primary key of the table.

Since the primary key of any database table has to be unique, your query is failing as the combination that you are adding in your query must already be existing in the table. In order to fix this, you can apply a check before inserting any new row.